# Empty regular expression

Tags: formal-languages, regular-expressions

When my professor introduced regular expressions, he said that the empty string is the simplest regular expression, where it matches everything. How can this be true? I would think the empty string matches nothing, but perhaps I have an incorrect Computer Science understanding of what "null" or "empty" means.

Answer (score 2):

The empty regular expression matches one string: the empty string. That's not everything (most strings aren't the empty string) but it also isn't nothing (the empty string is a string, and the regular expression does match it).

In many programming languages with "regular expression" (regex) support, the default when you match a regex against a string is to consider it a match if any substring matches. Since every string has the empty string as a substring, the empty regular expression will match any string. But that convention isn't standard in computer science.

Comment: How does every string have the empty string as the substring? Is this the same logic that the empty set is defined to be a subset of every set?

Comment: yes, such statements are known as vacuously true statements(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth)

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you might be getting confused about the difference between the regular expression that matches only the empty string (often written $\varepsilon$, or sometimes written $\lambda$; it recognizes the language $\{\varepsilon\}$) vs a regular expression that does not match any string (often written $\emptyset$; it recognizes the language $\emptyset$, i.e., the empty set) vs the empty regular expression (which, by convention, matches only the empty string).

See [What is the difference between the set containing the empty string and the set containing nothing at all?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/156734/755), [What's the difference between phi and lambda in regular expression?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/119157/755), [What are Lambda productions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/74976/755).